# How I can alter the probability of an event in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability

I have a network with N = 5 nodes. The probability that a new connection exit node "Ni" is:

`P(N1) = P(N2) = P(N3)  = P(N4) = P(N5) = 1/5`

And the sum of all P(Ni) = 1.

which is a uniform distribution. I would like, nodes N3 and N5 had more chance to leave the rest. For example:

`P(N1) = P(N2) = P(N4) = 2/15`

`P(N3) = P(N5) = 3/10`

And the sum of all P(Ni) = 1.

The code I am using now is this:

```
nodes = 21;
NODES=(1:nodes);
R=randperm(nodes);
nodeSource=NODES(R(1));
nodeDestin=NODES(R(2));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html)

```
nodeSource = randsample(1:numel(P), numel(P), true, P)
```